# Splitting a string on multiple separators in PHP

Tags: php, preg-split

I can split a string with a comma using `preg_split`, like

```
$words = preg_split('/[,]/', $string);
```

How can I use a dot, a space and a semicolon to split string with any of these?

PS. I couldn't find any relevant example on the PHP preg_split page, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$string = "foo bar baz; boo, bat";

$words = preg_split('/[,.\s;]+/', $string);

var_dump($words);
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "boo", "bat"]
```

*The Pattern explained*

`[]` is a character class, a character class consists of multiple characters and matches to one of the characters which are inside the class

`.` matches the `.` Character, this does not need to be escaped *inside* character classes. Though this needs to be escaped when not in a character class, because `.` means "match any character".

`\s` matches whitespace

`;` to split on the semicolon, this needs not to be escaped, because it has not special meaning.

The `+` at the end ensures that spaces after the split characters do not show up as matches

Comment: @chh: The dot (`.`) is just a dot inside a character class and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess, escaping regex special characters is kind of a habit :-)

Answer (score 3):

The examples are there, not literally perhaps, but a split with multiple options for delimiter

```
$words = preg_split('/[ ;.,]/', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
<?php
$string = "blsdk.bldf,las;kbdl aksm,alskbdklasd";
$words = preg_split('/[,\ \.;]/', $string);

print_r( $words );
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blsdk
    [1] => bldf
    [2] => las
    [3] => kbdl
    [4] => aksm
    [5] => alskbdklasd
)
```

Comment: but, if there is no **dot(.), semi-colon(;), space or comma(,)**, then how to it should it done.

Comment: Open another question with your specific question. This question specifically asked about dot, semicolon, space, or comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = preg_split('/[\,\.\ ]/', $string);
```

Comment: Too \mu\ch u\necce\ss\ary \e\s\c\a\p\i\n\g \i\n thi\s \ans\wer.

Answer (score 1):

just add these chars to your expression

```
$words = preg_split('/[;,. ]/', $string);
```

**EDIT**: thanks to Igoris Azanovas, escaping dot in character class is not needed ;)

Comment: No need to escape . inside brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = preg_split('/[,\.\s;]/', $string);
```